# Org-mode: Source block doesn't respect parent buffer indentation

Tags: org-mode, indentation

When I edit a source block it comes out in the `org-mode` buffer like this:

```
- Item 1
  Text indented two spaces here under list entry

  #+BEGIN_SRC ruby
class Name
end
  #+END_SRC
```

But it should be indented like this:

```
- Item 1
  Text indented two spaces here under list entry

  #+BEGIN_SRC ruby
  class Name
  end
  #+END_SRC
```

How do I need to configure `org-mode` to solve this issue?

Comment: What are your values for 'org-src-preserve-indentation' and 'org-edit-src-content-indentation'?

Comment: (setq org-src-preserve-indentation t
      org-edit-src-content-indentation 2)

Comment: @TadAshlock, thanks for your hint, I changed my setting,
(setq org-src-peserve-indentation nil org-edit-src-content-indentation 0) . this solved my problem.

Comment: Worth mentioning, the manual page on this: http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation nil 
      org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `C-c'` to edit the block using the ruby-mode (or any other mode you specified for babel). Now you can indent the whole buffer according to the ruby-mode. Leave using `C-c'` again and your block should be indented now.

You could also create a function or a macro to run those steps for you, to automatize the process, if you wish.

Comment: I did edit babel source code with `C-c '`.

Comment: Ops, sorry, I didn't imply that

Comment: C-c' is freakin AWESOME